# Pentaho connecting to Cloudera Impala error

Tags: pentaho, impala

I'm trying to set up a connection in Pentaho Data Integrator to Cloudera Impala, but I keep getting the following error:

> Driver class 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.ImpalaSimbaDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Cloudera Impala' driver (jar file) is installed.
> Could not initialize class org.apache.hive.jdbc.ImpalaSimbaDriver
>
>
> org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
> Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
>
> Driver class 'org.apache.hive.jdbc.ImpalaSimbaDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Cloudera Impala' driver (jar file) is installed.
> Could not initialize class org.apache.hive.jdbc.ImpalaSimbaDriver

I downloaded the driver from Cloudera; put all the files in the in lib folder and CDH54 folder. Also, I added the environmental variable CLASSPATH making it point to the folder containing my .jar files.

The connection from Tableau to Impala works fine, and I can also connect from SQL Workbench to the distribution.

Am I missing something?

Thank you for any response.

Comment: I feel that its class path issue , If that is not the reason then it is not correct version of  jar file where "ImpalaSimbaDriver" class is present its not there. your client is trying to load this class and in that process it will lookout for this class.

Comment: I find it strange that the Pentaho documentation with Impala doesn't mention a Simba Driver anywhere. Any suggestions on how to modify the class path? I'm to sure how Pentaho obtains the correct class path, am in understanding that the jars should be in the designated Hadoop distribution folder and lib.

Comment: Hi Im not sure whether you have done in the same way. If not pls have a look at this http://cdn.simba.com/products/Impala/doc/Simba_Impala_JDBC_InstallGuide.pdf

Comment: seems like there is a license for this simba driver. as mentioned in the above doc link "Simba License File
Before you can use the Simba JDBC Driver for Cloudera Impala, you must place the
SimbaClouderaImpalaJDBCDriver.lic file in the same directory as the ImpalaJDBC3.jar,
ImpalaJDBC4.jar, or ImpalaJDBC41.jar file.
"

Comment: Were you able to fix this ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It is still not working unfortunately.. I followed all the steps, but keep getting the same errors.

Comment: Funny, I tried connecting to Hadoop with Pentaho DI 5.4 and that seems to work through the regular Impala connection on CDH53.

Comment: Is it version mismatch?

Comment: Not sure. I copied the CDH53 folder to my Pentaho DI 6.0 distribution and I still keep getting errors there - however not about the driver anymore so I suppose that's one thing that's resolved.